# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to a Java Jar or .NET DLL?

Tags: java, javascript, .net, deployment, jar

New to JavaScript and am wondering if **all** JavaScript has to be "deployed" as individual `.js` files, or if there are ways to bundle/package multiple JS files as a component, like a Java `.jar` or a .NET `.dll`.

For instance, if I have a collection of, say, 30 JS files that make up a reusable library of JS objects and functions, is there a way to package these as a single deployable component or am I stuck copying-n-pasting all 30 files into every project where I want to use them?

What's the norm here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2018 update:** You can use CommonJS or ES modules and package them with an appropriate tool like Browserify, webpack, Parcel, etc.

JavaScript can't be compiled (before sending it to the client) of course; the closest equivalent is just to minify them, then glue all the files together. For minification, I personally like [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com); as for the gluing, it's pretty easy to do with your command-line tools. For example:

```
cat script1.js >> all.js
cat script2.js >> all.js
# etc.
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking more than correcting but modern JS interpreters are actually JITs (Just in Time Compilers). Which is to say after some initial parsing and prep-work it compiles into byte code on the fly rather than being parsed, tokenized and interpreted by run-time code directly. Python does something similar but you can actually save Python as binary after running a program once.

Comment: @ErikReppen: Yeah, I meant "before it goes to the browser". Sorry, answer updated. (And yes that's *so* nitpicking `;)`)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use all the content of all the files, you could consolidate their contents into a single js file using a text editor.  Having 30 separate .js files will slow down a page load since 30 requests have to be made.  You can further reduce the file size by using a JavaScript "minifier", such as http://jscompress.com/ or http://www.minifyjavascript.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's called `namespace`.
[This](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/) is one explanations blog about it.
[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19030/Namespaces-in-JavaScript) is a nice tutorial .

Comment: "Google it up" isn't an answer. Please add an example or a description.

Comment: I'll remove my -1, but keep in mind that simply linking to other resources is considered bad form for an answer and links can go dead. *Consider summarizing the contents, adding an example, or adding a description, please.*

Answer (score 0):

... best you can hope for is to minify, combine into one file, maybe look into an automatic build system for it. Hover, when you go to build that single file, be very careful, because the compression/minification process can definitely break stuff. Consider running the sourcefiles through jsLint. Plan on spending a good deal of time on testing.

Answer (score 0):

Although Javascript is an interpreted language, Google claims that it CAN be compiled. This is what their [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) does. It's a bit different than minimization because the code is also optimized for faster execution.